# Structure within Union

Tags: c++, c

I'm a newbie to C Programming.

What is the advantage of using structure within a union instead of using structure directly?
Many of my leads use structure with in a union instead of using it directly.
Please let me know the advantage of using structure within union.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}MY_STRUCT;


typedef union
{
    MY_STRUCT my_structure;
}MY_UNION;
```

Comment: Did you ask *them* what is the benefit?

Comment: Yes I have asked them, they have said some bit manipulation stuffs. I can't able to understand clearly what they intend to tell.

Comment: [This story](http://kcbx.net/~tellswor/end-ham.htm) just seems fitting.

Comment: Can you explain me, how this stuff works?

Comment: @Joe That's excellent!

Comment: From the code you have posted, there is no advantage. If there was another field in the union, it might make sense. If you are a newbie, I would avoid unions.

Comment: @Charlie Burns : Up to me in case of structure memory will be allocated for each elements contained in it where as in case of unions memory will be allocated with respect to the largest element in the structure. What if many structure variables were used inside a union?

Comment: The memory will be allocated with respect to the largest element in the **union** not the struct. Your not saving any bytes or making anyones lives easier. You might as well send someone a letter inside of an envelope inside of another envelope that might not take up more space.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 3):

`union`s are used to save space in `struct`s. Suppose you have a structure for the items in a catalog. The catalog contains three items each with stock numbers and price with some other information as

- **Books**: Title, author, num of pages
- **Mugs**: Design
- **Design**, colors, available, sizes available

One possible `struct` for that is:

```
struct catalog_item{
    int stock_num;
    double price;
    int item_type; 
    int title[TITLE_LEN];
    int author[AUTHOR_LEN];
    int num_pages;
    char design[DESIGN_LEN];
    int colors;
    int sizes;
};
```

But somehow this `struct` wastes space, since only part of the information in `struct` is common to all in catalog. For, ex: no need to store `design`, `color` and `sizes` for book item type.

By using a `union` inside `catalog_item`, space can be reduced

```
struct catalog_item{
    int stock_num;
    double price;
    int item_type; 
    union{
         struct{ 
            int title[TITLE_LEN];
            int author[AUTHOR_LEN];
            int num_pages;
         } book; 
        struct{
            char design[DESIGN_LEN];
        } mug;

        struct{
            char design[DESIGN_LEN];
            int colors;
            int sizes;
        } shirt;

   } item;  
};
```

---

<sub>Above example is taken from the book [C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition](http://www.amazon.in/C-Programming-2e-K-King/dp/0393979504).</sub>

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. In your case any one of the internal structures will be used at a time so coding in this way will not allocate separate memory for other two unused structures. Is it so?

Comment: @Shree; Memory will be allocated for largest one, i.e, for member `book` only. Memory allocation for other members  will be overlapped to the same space as per need.  So yes at a time only one inner struct can be used.

Comment: This answers my question "When to use structure within an union". Thanks a lot